# Is showResult a global function name in SSJS?

Tags: lotus-notes

I used showResult as a function name in a script library and when it's called, an error
 [TypeError] Error calling method showResult(string) on an object of type 'object[JavaScript Object]'
occurred. If the function is defined in a xpage or renamed as showResult2, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Reference tab in the Script Editor allows you to see all the global functions. If showResult is a function, it's defined elsewhere (e.g. in a script library).